# Why are my 2 Divs within my parent Div container not aligning next to eachother?

Tags: html, css

I have tried all sorts of things to try and get this working, I'm a little dated with html markup so please forgive me but i'm sure my problem can easily be solved. I have 2 divs (1 image **logo** and 1 flash object **flame** ) which I would like to center inside a container div which I would like to be centered with any browser screen resolution. I would also like the horizontal scroll bars to only appear when the browser window is below 800px wide hence the min-width:800px (this works ok) on the container div. my child divs keep appearing above and below each other and when I set them to absolute positioning the just appear to the left ontop of each other.....I just want everything to be aligned centrally and both divs at the top of the screen, can someone please help and point me in the right direction.

Thanks
Andy

```
.container {
margin-left: 0 auto;
margin-right: 0 auto;
min-width:800px;
width: 100%;
height: 500px;
background-color:#F00;
}
.logo {
margin: 0 auto;
position:absolute;
vertical-align:top;
display:inline-block;
width:1059px;
height:136px;   
}
.flame {
margin: 0 auto;
vertical-align:top;
position:absolute;
display:inline-block;
width:861px;
height:134px;
}
```

Comment: Add the html too please. To not have scrollbars unless the window is less than 800px is not really possible without hiding content.  Your logo alone is 1059px wide, any screen smaller than this will trigger scrollbars.

Comment: Please add the HTML too or create a demo on http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: still not working :( js fiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/N6rTt/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
.container {
margin:auto;
width:800px;
height: 500px;
background-color:#F00;
}
.logo {
margin:auto;
float:left;
width:450px;
height:136px;   
background-color:#096;
}
.flame {

margin:auto;
float:left;
width:350px;
height:134px;
background-color:#099;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="logo">LOGO GOES HERE</div>
        <div class="flame">FLASH CONTENT GOES HERE</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Using floats, you can make your divs stack up next to each other. However, the sum of the widths of the divs must be less than or equal to the width of the container, otherwise the 2nd div will appear below the first div. Your container will also always be centered to the browser. Also, if the width of the browser is below 800px (width of the container), horizontal scroll bars will appear.
One last thing, this code centers the container but does not center your divs if the sum of the widths of the floated element are less than the width of the container.
You can go through this [link](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/35-floats-and-clearing/#centeringfloats) to learn how to do that as well.

EDITED:
Alternately, if you know the sum of the widths of the logo and the flash banner, which I think you do, you can create a div with width equal to the sum and apply a margin:auto property to it. Involves use of an extra div and prior knowledge about the width of your logos and flash banners, but I think will suit your purpose.
Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks Fahad, I am not in work until tomorrow but thanks for the coding above, I will give your code a try tomorrow and report back to how I get on :) fingers crossed I'll get it working correctly, cheers.

Comment: I will post a js fiddle link below which shows you my code exactly including logo and flash widths & sums, I am trying to cater for all screen sizes hence why my container is 1920px x 1080px hopefully using your information I can still acheive what I want with this large size :)

Answer (score 0):

**Final version**

To sum it up - the task was basically this:

- have two elements width different widths be aligned alongside in one row
- this row should always be centered as kind of a header
- only when the screen is smaller than 800px a horizontally scrollbar should appear
- the non-visible edges are trimmed on the left and the right side

**This is a possible solution:**

[Try before buy on jsfillde.net](http://jsfiddle.net/zLWbd/)

And a little explanation:

**HTML markup**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="center">
        <img src="" alt="">
        <object></object>    
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 800px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

div.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 134px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div.center {
    position: relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 800px;
    height: 100%;
}

div.center > img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -499px;
}

div.center > object {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 560px;
}
```

**On "How it works"**

The first div `wrapper` spans an area from the left side to the right side. This is the space which is always visible. To cut off the edges I used `overflow: hidden;` on that element. So everything that sticks out will be invisible.

The second div `center` is placed in the middle of the viewport using `margin: 0 auto`. It has a fixed width. I used `800px` because this was the desired min-width in the question. It will work with any other wide, too.

Now it's time to align the two header elements. Both have a fixed width. In this case the image is *1059px* and the object is *861px*, making it a total of **1920px**. The middle of those elements would be obvious at *960px*. Our container's `center` is actually at *400px*, because the min-width of the page is *800px*. So the actually meeting point of both elements is at *560px* within this container, as we have a *160px* shift. So for the object it's easy: simple set `left: 560px;`. But the left container must be placed, that it ends at this point. We had a width of *1059px* and substract it from the *560px* and get the final value of `left: -499px;`.

As the container in the middle is centered, both elements will be centered, too. And as the `wrapper`'s overflow is hidden, both edges will be cut off at the end of the viewport. Without any scrollbars visible.

At the end, there's only one thing left: Set `min-width:800px` on the `<body>`-tag, so that the scrollbars get visible as soon, as the window is smaller than *800px*.

**First answer**

`position: absolute` takes the element out of there parents flow, except you set the parents `position` explicitly:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}
```

This should do the trick, but it didn't test it with your markup.

Comment: Hi all thanks for the swift replies, much appreciated :) 

I have tried altering the CSS to what Cecil Theodore suggested but the 2 divs are still sitting above and below each other. What I want is for them to be centered at the top of the screen next to each other then if the browser window is reduced the body stays centered - this means users with a 1024 x 768 screen resolution will still see the center of the web page where the main content is going to be and people with larger screen resolutions get a little bit more of the background image.

please see the fiddle below

Comment: OK, let me get this straight. :) You want that the fire and header image are placed on top of each other? And you want it to be centered, like a background image, where the edges on the left and right side are cut off on smaller screens?

Comment: I want the header image (left div) next to the fire image (right div) both centered inside a container div that will always keep them both together at the top of the page and center them when the browser window or screen resolution is reduced, and yes the edges need to cut off on smaller screens to keep the content centered :) - sorry insertusernamehere I lack a little knowledge, thanks for your patience.

Comment: when I say i want them both to stay next to eachother but both in the center of the browser window. The edges of both divs should be cut off if the screen resolution or browser window is reduced, I hope this all makes sense :)

Comment: @AndyTurford I don't really know what you mean by next to each another. Is it like they float, means: the right border of the logo touches the left border of the animation like they are really in one line?

Comment: Yes thats correct I did try to float them but everytime I resized the browser window or changed resolution it pushed the flame video below the logo image?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code, this seems to keep everything niceley aligned although I still don't understand why the container is only 800px wide when the 2 graphic/flash widths combined are 1920px? I thought the container had to be the same size as the two Divs inside it :/ anyway that doesn't really matter. The only issue I have now is the horizontal scroll bars are still showing, I would only like them to show when the browser or screen resolution goes below 800px wide? hope you can help :)

Comment: @AndyTurford I think I nailed it down to your needs. See the updated answer and explanation. Hope, this is working for you in the end.

Comment: Wow!! thanks man, it works brilliantly, I sort of understand what your saying with the container widths and image object positioning, I never knew html and CSS coding was so in depth!! I've got so much more to learn lol!! now one last thing, srry I know i'm a pain :D when I try and view the site on my Acer Iconia tablet, the logo displays ok but the flash video flame is squashed up, any ideas? the screen resolution on these are 1280 x 800. Thanks

Comment: I'm glad I could help. I'm not sure with the tablet, but maybe you have to set the `object` to `display:block` and set its width and height manually again using CSS. I also chopped out some of your initial code within the object. Maybe you have to restore those parts.

Comment: I tried the display:block and manual sizes to the CSS, this didn't work so if i replace the old flash code with your cleaned up version, where do I put the image file parameter if the browser is non flash compliant, e.g. I-pad etc.. Thanks again, you have really been a great help and I do appreciate your time :)

Comment: @AndyTurford please approve the answer if it's working. I'm sorry that I can't assist you further with this mobile optimization.

Comment: Tried replacing the flash code with your original cleaned up code and flash element is still squashed, tried changing flash width & height sizes to 100%, still no joy :/ must be the new code for the wrapper or something I don't know :D will keep trying though. Yes your code is working great, many thanks :)

Comment: sorry to bother you again and I fully understand if you can't help me but I think I found what is causing the flash video being squashed up on the tablet, it seems to be the overflow: hidden; css in the div.wrapper, when I remove it, the video displays fine, but obviously I lose my centering and horizontal scroll bar comes back? are there any other overflow attributes I could apply to the div.wrapper instead? just fishing that's all :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
margin-left: 0 auto;
margin-right: 0 auto;
min-width:800px;
width: 100%;
height: 500px;
background-color:#F00;
**position:relative;**
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 800px){
html{
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
}
```